# Is the way I have passed the parameter wrong in selection function?

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do is get the text from a drop-down list. When I pass `this` to the function it gives an error which says the options in  "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined" so want to know whether the value I am passing is correct or not

```
<form>

    <select name="hello" onchange="selection(this);">
        <option value ="1">name</option>
        <option value="2">address</option>
        <option value="3">street</option>
        <option value="4">city</option>
    </select>


</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function selection(textValue){
        console.log(textValue.hello);
         var selectedvalue = selectedValue(textValue.hello);
         console.log("selectedvalue");

    }
    function selectedValue(newname){

        return newname.options[newname.selectedIndex].text;
    }

    </script>
```

The output should be the text value that user select like name, address etc

Comment: Your code is not too clear. Where are you thinking the `hello` property is?

Comment: You don't need to pass `this`. Just directly use `this` instead of `textValue`.

Comment: the name for select list

Comment: i checked but it doesn't work it gives the same error as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why the error is happening is explained in the comments of the code below.

```js
    function selection(textValue){
        //console.log(textValue.hello);
         
         // pass the object to selectedValue, not the string
         var selectedvalue = selectedValue(textValue);
         
         // remove quotes around selectedvalue
         console.log(selectedvalue);

    }
    
    function selectedValue(newname){

        return newname.options[newname.selectedIndex].text;
    }
```

```html
    <select id="hello" name="hello" onchange="selection(this);">
        <option value ="1">name</option>
        <option value="2">address</option>
        <option value="3">street</option>
        <option value="4">city</option>
    </select>
```